# Replace wire terminal connector to heating element

Tags: wire, stove, range

I have GE Range JB640SR3SS and one of the element wire connector got burnt out:

https://www.searspartsdirect.com/model-number/jb640sr3ss/0432/0124111.html

I cut it and here are the photos front and back

[image]

[image]

I have two options: either replace entire wire with the end connector terminal or find the terminal only and crimp it myself. I seem NOT be able to find the terminal myself.

This is the closet I can find but they don't seem to look right

https://www.appliancepartspros.com/pro-high-temp-non-tjma02875-1-ap5642027.html

https://www.delcity.net/store/High-Temperature-Push-On-Terminals/p_802002.h_187294.r_IF1003?mkwid=s&crid=38094426869&mp_kw=&mp_mt=&gclid=CjwKCAiA767jBRBqEiwAGdAOr-hFcdVj0i9nhaiTwITPwX6DHKmzIp6biwXeEMld-1XgoWL019dWeRoCDl4QAvD_BwE

I called several local appliance repair shops and they said GE doesn't list the wiring assembly.

Any idea how I can repair this? Beside buying a new range.

Thanks.

Comment: Be very careful, high temp's require special connectors in this case a female spade not the generic tin plated copper that are not rated for high temps. The high temp crimp connectors may look different , this is ok the width is normally the only thing I look at other than wire size or temp rating.

Answer (score 2):

The ones from AppliancePros are what you need, except that you may need a larger gauge size (wire side) if you want to gang the two wires together. On the other side (terminal side) it's hard to tell if it 1/4 inch from the photo but they are the most common. More importantly you should investigate why it burnt in the first place. If it's an older stove I wouldn't be too concerned because that happens over time due to corrosion on the terminals, heat speeds up oxidation, oxidation causes resistance, resistance causes heat. Just clean up the male side with a bit of sandpaper and reconnect. If it a newer stove and corrosion isn't evident I'd recommend having an appliance technician check it out.

[image]

I know your crimper is a little different but the idea is the same. You strip back a little bit of insulation and insert it into the terminal and crimp tight. You shouldn't be able to pull it out once done.

Comment: How do I crimp it? I bought this but not sure if it is the right tool Gardner Bender
Terminal and Crimping Tool Kit Model # GS-67K
https://www.homedepot.com/p/Gardner-Bender-Terminal-and-Crimping-Tool-Kit-GS-67K/202518592

Answer (score 2):

You definitely need high-temp nickel-plated spade or flag connectors. AWG 14 wire gauge is typical. I bought a whole kit of high-temp connectors at local full service/specialty electronics shop, it contained two sizes ring, 16-14 gauge wire spades & flags, about 15-20 of each for about $14 CAD. Seems lik enough for a lifetime of clothes dryer heater, oven heater or broiler element wire lead ends.

As always, make sure you have enough lead wire left to strip back PAST any overheat-induced copper corrosion, otherwise replacing or splicing will be happening. It's not good to subject connectors to sideways or even axial tension/bending stress.